# PowerShell - Import-Csv - referencing a column by its position

Tags: csv, powershell

When dealing with csv files using the cmdlet Import-Csv in PowerShell, is there an easy / elegant way to query a column by its position instead of the header name?

Example with this data:

```
row1, abc
row2, def
row3, xyz
```

The below command works fine if the file has "header_column2" as the header of the 2nd column:

```
import-csv data.csv | where {$_.header_column2 -eq "xyz"}
```

I am looking for something like this (which obviously doesn't work!):

```
import-csv data.csv | where {$_.[2] -eq "xyz"}
```

I know that if I don't have headers in the file I could use the -Header parameter to specify those, but I am looking for something quick and handy to write on the fly for various files, where headers are not relevant.

Many thanks!

Comment: `@($_.PSObject.Properties)[2].Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @PetSerAl doesn't understand the difference between comments and answers here at StackOverflow, I'll provide a similar answer.

You can list the properties in the object using `.PSObject.Properties`. This returns an `IEnumerable` that doesn't know about indexes, but if you convert it to an array, it will.

```
@($_.PSObject.Properties)[2].Value
```