# How to change each column and row from a CSV file to upper case?

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, uppercase, psobject

existing code:

```
$in = Import-Csv .\in.csv
$TextInfo = (New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).TextInfo;
$in | ForEach-Object { $_.name = $textInfo.ToUpper($_.name) }
$in | Export-Csv .\out.csv
```

This will convert the case `ToUpper` or can be `ToTitleCase` optionally.

How would each column be iterated?

Tried to get the column names as below.  Just need to better understand how to iterate each column rather than a specific named column.  How is the count of CSV columns determined?  How is each column referenced in a loop as above?

Ideally, using the REPL console as below.

```
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $in = Import-Csv .\in.csv
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $TextInfo = (New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")).TextInfo;
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $in.PSObject.Properties.Name
Count
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot
IsReadOnly
IsFixedSize
IsSynchronized
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $in | Format-Table

alpha      beta       charlie    delta
-----      ----       -------    -----
sdkljgsdf  bdgfhgfnhm ngfgfddfsg dfhgsdfg
gfjdsaklbf dfbdfgfn   vfsdafdfbn fgjtyj
bdgfkl     dsfsd      vgngfas    dsfhgtj
dsbmnkl    nggfn      bfdsda     edtshdgf
asdfkl     sdagfdfh   vbdfdngt   ngfggj


PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $in.PSObject.Properties[2].Value
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
```

Also:

```
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop> $in | Get-Member -MemberType Properties


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name    MemberType   Definition
----    ----------   ----------
alpha   NoteProperty string alpha=sdkljgsdf
beta    NoteProperty string beta=bdgfhgfnhm
charlie NoteProperty string charlie=ngfgfddfsg
delta   NoteProperty string delta=dfhgsdfg


PS C:\Users\Nick\Desktop>
```

will get the column names:  alpha, beta, etc.  But how would each be passed and iterated to change the case of all "cells" as above?

see also:

[PowerShell - Import-Csv - referencing a column by its position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35376186/22063140)

[How to convert a specific CSV column to TitleCase with PowerShell from the REPL console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76466687/22063140)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34131869/22063140

Comment: I want to iterate each column.  Not a specific column @SantiagoSquarzon and I can kinda get each column name as above.

Comment: His last example from that answer explicitly says: `# Iterate over all properties and modify their values.` then uses `foreach ($prop in $_.psobject.Properties) {`. This is how you "iterate over each column from each row"

Comment: Maybe the question is asked poorly.  I'll try again.

Comment: Did you try the code in the latest example of that answer? There are 2 loops, an outer `ForEach-Object` which loops thru each row then there is an inner `foreach` which loops thru each property (column). If that didn't do what you were expecting then edit your question and I'll reopen it

Comment: yes @SantiagoSquarzon I was just taking it to be a diff question.  Thx for all your efforts.  Above and beyond.